# Factorize code with custom functions in Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to factorize my code in Cloud Functions in order to improve readability and maintenance. The code below works but after waiting for all Promises to complete with `Promises.all()`, the code timeout.

The things I don't understand is that :

1. It works great and complete without timeout when `toiletJsonObject["fields"]["adresse"] = formatAddress(toiletJsonObject["fields"]["adresse"])` is commented
2. If it works without the line above, the timeout should be due to the `formatAddress()` function. However, this function in not an async one and just return a `string` synchronously. Maybe that's what I misunderstand.

So my questions are :

- How to correct my code to avoid timeout?
- what's the best way to factorize code with custom functions that are only accessible inside the file and therefore does not need `export` ?

The entire code :

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

export const tempoCF = functions.firestore.document("/tempo/{docId}").onCreate(async () => {
    console.log("onCreate")

    const settings = { method: "Get" }

    const metaUrl = "https://opendata.paris.fr/api/datasets/1.0/sanisettesparis/"

    const toiletUpdateDateRef = db.collection('toilets').doc("updateDate")
    try {

        // Get meta data to check last update date
        const metaResponse = await fetch(metaUrl, settings)
        const metaJson = await metaResponse.json()
        const metaUpdateDate = metaJson["metas"]["modified"]
        const lastUpdatedDateDoc = await toiletUpdateDateRef.get()

        if (!lastUpdatedDateDoc.exists) {
            console.log("No existing date document, create one and add last update date : " + metaUpdateDate)
            await fetchDataFromURL()
            return toiletUpdateDateRef.set({ "lastUpdateDate": metaUpdateDate })
        } else {
            const lastUpdateDate = lastUpdatedDateDoc.data()["lastUpdateDate"]
            // If date from meta data newer that saved date : get data and update
            if (new Date(lastUpdateDate) < new Date(metaUpdateDate)) {
                console.log("New data available, update database")
                await fetchDataFromURL()
                return toiletUpdateDateRef.set({ "lastUpdateDate": metaUpdateDate })
            }
            else {
                console.log("No new data available, do nothing")
                return null
            }
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }
}

);

async function fetchDataFromURL() {
    const dataUrl = "https://opendata.paris.fr/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=sanisettesparis&q=&rows=-1"
    const settings = { method: "Get" }

    try {
        const response = await fetch(dataUrl, settings)
        const json = await response.json()
        const promises = []
        console.log("fetch data and add toilets to collection")
        json["records"].forEach(toiletJsonObject => {
            delete toiletJsonObject["fields"]["geo_shape"]

            toiletJsonObject["fields"]["adresse"] = formatAddress(toiletJsonObject["fields"]["adresse"])
            console.log("after updating adresse field: " + toiletJsonObject["fields"].toString())

            const p = db.collection("toilets").doc(toiletJsonObject["recordid"]).set(toiletJsonObject["fields"])
            promises.push(p)
        })
        console.log("finished creating promises. Wait for all to complete")
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }

    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }
}

const linkWords = ["de", "des", "du", "le"]
const linkLetters = ["l", "d"]
const firstWordsAddress = ["face", "opposé", "au"]
const alwaysLowerCaseWords = ["ville", "rue"]

function formatAddress(address) {
    let processedAddress = ""
    if (address != null) {
        //if (address.length <= 1) processedAddress = address.toUpperCase();
        // Split string into list of words
        var wordsList = address.split(' ')
            .filter((word) => {
                // If there is a word in front of the street number, don't use it
                if (firstWordsAddress.includes(word.toLowerCase())) return false
                // Else use it
                return true
            })
        var capitalizedList = wordsList.map((word) => {
            const lowerCaseWord = word.toLowerCase() //TOSTRING ?
            // If current word is a link word, don't capitalize
            if (linkWords.includes(lowerCaseWord))
                return lowerCaseWord
            // If current word is a link letter, add ' char
            else if (linkLetters.includes(lowerCaseWord))
                return lowerCaseWord + '\''
            // If current word should always be in lower case, don't capitalize
            else if (alwaysLowerCaseWords.includes(lowerCaseWord))
                return word.toLowerCase() //TOSTRING
            // Else, capitalize the word
            return word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substr(1).toLowerCase()
        });
        // Always capitalize first word of the address
        capitalizedList[0] = capitalizedList[0][0].toUpperCase() + capitalizedList[0].substr(1).toLowerCase()
        processedAddress = capitalizedList.join(' ')
        processedAddress = processedAddress.replace("\' ", "\'")
        processedAddress = processedAddress.trim()
    }
    return processedAddress
}
```

Comment: Hi, FYI, running your CF on the Firebase platform (i.e. after deployment) took 15 seconds. The problem is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Do you think it might be my emulator ? Do you agree that the `formatAddress()` shouldn't be a problem as it terminates right away ? Also, there is a weird behavior, sometimes the function works normally and sometimes I got a timeout. Could it be due to the fact that the documents are already created into the collection ?

Comment: Do you think it might be my emulator ? => I don't know. Do you agree that the formatAddress() shouldn't be a problem as it terminates right away ? => Yes I agree.  Could it be due to the fact that the documents are already created into the collection ? => At first sight your code correctly implements the life cycle CF management, i.. returning a Promise when all asynchronous job is completed.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try in production!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the `formatAddress()` helper function you defined, there doesn't appear to be an issue with it in it's current form. It can happily run through the entire list of 644 addresses ~210 times per second.

Any timeouts are instead likely to be caused by performing so many database writes in quick succession. When running `fetchDataFromURL()`, you "spam" the Firestore server with a request for each toilet object you are uploading.

The best-practice approach would be to compile a [Batched Write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) and then commit the result once you've finished processing the data.

As stated in that [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes):

> A batched write can contain up to 500 operations. Each operation in the batch counts separately towards your Cloud Firestore usage. Within a write operation, field transforms like `serverTimestamp`, `arrayUnion`, and `increment` each count as an additional operation.

*Note: The current list of field transforms includes `serverTimestamp`, `arrayUnion`, `arrayRemove`, and `increment`. Reference: [`FieldValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue)*

Creating/deleting/writing a document to Firestore is considered "one operation". Because a field transform requires reading the document, then writing data to that document, it is counted as "two operations".

Because a single batched write is limited to 500 operations, you should split your data up into smaller batched writes so that each batch is less than this 500 operations limit. The easiest way to achieve this would be to use this `MultiBatch` class (included below) that I've updated from one of [my old answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64799980/3068190).

- If the data you are writing to a Cloud Firestore document is just basic data, use one of `multibatch.create()`, `multibatch.delete()`, `multibatch.set()`, or `multibatch.update()`. Each time one of these is called, the internal operations counter is increased by `1`.
- If the data you are writing to Cloud Firestore contains any [`FieldValue`
  transforms](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue), use one of `multibatch.transformCreate()`, `multibatch.transformDelete()`, `multibatch.transformSet()`, or `multibatch.transformUpdate()`. Each time one of these is called, the internal operations counter is increased by `2`.
- Once the internal counter exceeds 500, it automatically starts a new batched write and adds it to it's internal list.
- When you've queued up all your data ready to send off to Firestore, call `multibatch.commit()`.

```js
console.log("Fetching data from third-party server...")
const response = await fetch(dataUrl, settings)
const json = await response.json()

console.log("Data obtained. Parsing as Firestore documents...")
const batch = new MultiBatch(db)
json["records"].forEach(toiletJsonObject => {
    delete toiletJsonObject["fields"]["geo_shape"]

    toiletJsonObject["fields"]["adresse"] = formatAddress(toiletJsonObject["fields"]["adresse"])
    console.log("after updating adresse field: " + toiletJsonObject["fields"].toString())

    batch.set(db.collection("toilets").doc(toiletJsonObject["recordid"]), toiletJsonObject["fields"])
})

console.log("Finished parsing. Committing data to Firestore...")
const results = await batch.commit() // see notes about MultiBatch#commit()
console.log("Finished data upload!")

return results;
```

```js
import { firestore } from "firebase-admin";

/**
 * Helper class to compile an expanding `firestore.WriteBatch`.
 *
 * Using an internal operations counter, this class will automatically start a
 * new `firestore.WriteBatch` instance when it detects it has hit the operations
 * limit of 500. Once prepared, you can commit the batches together.
 *
 * Note: `FieldValue` transform operations such as `serverTimestamp`, 
 * `arrayUnion`, `arrayRemove`, `increment` are counted as two operations. If
 * your written data makes use of one of these, you should use the appropriate
 * `transformCreate`, `transformSet` or `transformUpdate` method so that the 
 * internal counter is correctly increased by 2 (the normal versions only 
 * increase the counter by 1).
 * 
 * If not sure, just use `delete`, `transformCreate`, `transformSet`, or
 * `transformUpdate` functions for every operation as this will make sure you
 * don't exceed the limit.
 * 
 * @author Samuel Jones [MIT License] (@samthecodingman) 
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66692467/3068190
 * @see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions
 * @see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue
 */
export class MultiBatch {
  constructor(dbRef) {
    this.dbRef = dbRef;
    this.committed = false;
    this.currentBatch = this.dbRef.batch();
    this.currentBatchOpCount = 0;
    this.batches = [this.currentBatch];
  }

  _getCurrentBatch(count) {
    if (this.committed) throw new Error("MultiBatch already committed.");
    if (this.currentBatchOpCount + count > 500) {
      // operation limit exceeded, start a new batch
      this.currentBatch = this.dbRef.batch();
      this.currentBatchOpCount = 0;
      this.batches.push(this.currentBatch);
    }
    this.currentBatchOpCount += count;
    return this.currentBatch;
  }

  /** Creates the document, fails if it exists. */
  create(ref, data) {
    this._getCurrentBatch(1).create(ref, data);
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Creates the document, fails if it exists.
   *
   * Used for commands that contain serverTimestamp, arrayUnion, etc
   */
  transformCreate(ref, data) {
    this._getCurrentBatch(2).create(ref, data);
    return this;
  }

  /** Writes the document, creating/overwriting/etc as applicable. */
  set(ref, data, options = undefined) {
    this._getCurrentBatch(1).set(ref, data, options);
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Writes the document, creating/overwriting/etc as applicable.
   *
   * Used for commands that contain serverTimestamp, arrayUnion, etc
   */
  transformSet(ref, data, options = undefined) {
    this._getCurrentBatch(2).set(ref, data, options);
    return this;
  }

  /** Merges data into the document, failing if the document doesn't exist. */
  update(ref, data, ...fieldsOrPrecondition) {
    this._getCurrentBatch(1).update(ref, data, ...fieldsOrPrecondition);
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Merges data into the document, failing if the document doesn't exist.
   *
   * Used for commands that contain serverTimestamp, arrayUnion, etc
   */
  transformUpdate(ref, data, ...fieldsOrPrecondition) {
    this._getCurrentBatch(2).update(ref, data, ...fieldsOrPrecondition);
    return this;
  }

  /** Used when for basic update operations */
  delete(ref) {
    this._getCurrentBatch(1).delete(ref);
    return this;
  }

  /**
   *
   * Commits all of the batches to Firestore.
   *
   * Note: Unlike normal batch operations, this may cause one or more atomic
   * writes. One batch may succeed where others fail. By default, if any batch
   * fails, it will fail the whole promise. This can be suppressed by passing in
   * a truthy value as the first argument and checking the results returned by
   * this method.
   *
   * @param {boolean} [suppressErrors=false] Whether to suppress errors on a
   * per-batch basis.
   * @return {firestore.WriteResult[]} array containing an array of
   * `WriteResult` objects (and error-batch pairs if `suppressErrors=true`),
   * for each batch.
   */
  commit(suppressErrors = false) {
    this.committed = true;
    const mapCallback = suppressErrors
      ? (batch) => batch.commit().catch((error) => ({ error, batch }))
      : (batch) => batch.commit();

    return Promise.all(this.batches.map(mapCallback));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I see what's wrong now ! Could you please explain a bit more about `transform*()` and serverTimestamp, arrayUnion, and increment ? I don't get it neither on your old answer or on the documentation.

Comment: @Maxouille It was too much to add into a comment, so I've updated the answer. If you still need more explanation, ask a more pointed question such as "what is a serverTimestamp?" (which is a special placeholder value that tells the server to "insert current server time here")

Comment: Thank you, much more clear ! Also, is it best to use the JS file or convert it to TS and add types and return types ?

Comment: @Maxouille I personally write Cloud Functions in typescript as it leads to less functions crashing because of silly bugs. I actually have a typescript version of this file already [here](https://gist.github.com/samthecodingman/faba163b31488ab885bacefa7f63d121), I actually stripped the types out when I posted it here.

Comment: Great thank you, I translated the JS code to try it but i'll use your version. In general, do you mind resolving all the warnings that lint display ?

Comment: @Maxouille I follow the guidelines set down by the project I am working on. Each project will have a different set of styling guidelines, preferences and programmers. Adapt as necessary. If the warnings are simple correct, I will. The warnings are normally there for a reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230097/discussion-between-maxouille-and-samthecodingman).